# What is the best solution for a Web-Interface using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Today's Web is not a simple page - it's fully-featured interface.

A lot of solutions still "stuck" in old-way interface generation and manipulation - when you first build it with html and then manipulating elements.

What is the best solution if i want to develop "thick" client with minimum amout of pure html code? So all interface will be dynamic, generated and manipulated as objects with methods/events.

I've read about AngularJS and ExtJS, but it still seems not a "perfect" solution to me. Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: why Angular and ExtJS don't fit to your problem?

Comment: Angular still works as a html template engine, just on client-side. ExtJS can be my solution, but i'm still researching. And ExtJS is really expensive.

Comment: This question seems opinion based because it asks *What is the **best**...*.

Comment: Questions too broad needs mark as broad

Comment: you need good html to have a good interface, for best user results, don't let that part get auto-generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're describing is similar to what React.js / Flux are trying to accomplish. Perhaps add them to your list of frameworks to evaluate.

https://facebook.github.io/react/index.html

https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Comment: After almost 4 years of experiments i return to this problem and now the decision is to use React.